# How do I add a link to open a pdf file in a new window from my R shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I can use a() to add a hyperlink in to an external site from my Shiny app,

```
a("google",href="http://www.google.com")
```

but how do I make a link to open a pdf (or similar) file?  Seems like it should be simple, but I can't find any examples. My question is similar to this one:

[Add link to R Shiny Application so link opens in a new browser tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861102/add-link-to-r-shiny-application-so-link-opens-in-a-new-browser-tab)

but I don't know how to structure the href part- where do I put the file to be opened and how do I specify its location? I've tried simple things like http:///C:/Folder/file.pdf or file:///C:/Folder/file.pdf but the file is either not found or wont open.

I am new to shiny and have no html experience, so any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861102/add-link-to-r-shiny-application-so-link-opens-in-a-new-browser-tab if u put the file on the same path as your `ui.R`

Comment: I have the file in the ui.R path, but I can't get it to open. I either get "HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found" or "Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname)"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Put the pdf file inside the "www" directory (it has to be a subdirectory inside the directory where there are `ui.r` and `server.r` )

then you can run your shiny with:

```
a("click on me",target="_blank",href="myfile.pdf")
```

Comment: This works running Shiny locally but not (I get "not found" displayed in tab) when I deploy to Shiny.io. Any tips?